# Copy/duplicate SQL row with blob/text, How do that?

Tags: mysql, sql, text, duplicates, row

I would like to copy a SQL's row into the same table.
But in my table, I've a 'text' column.

With this SQL:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE produit2 ENGINE=MEMORY SELECT * FROM produit WHERE pdt_ID = 'IPSUMS';
UPDATE produit2 SET pdt_ID='ID_TEMP';
INSERT INTO produit SELECT * FROM produit2;
DROP TABLE produit2;
```

I get this error :

```
#1163 - The used table type doesn't support BLOB/TEXT columns
```

Here is my table :

```
pdt_ID varchar(6)
pdt_nom varchar(130)
pdt_stitre varchar(255)
pdt_accroche varchar(255)
pdt_desc text
pdt_img varchar(25)
pdt_pdf varchar(10)
pdt_garantie varchar(80)
edit_ID varchar(7)
scat_ID int(11)
pdt_asso1 char(3)
pdt_asso2 char(3) 
pdt_online tinyint(4)
```

It's possible to help me to duplicate row ? How?

Answer (score 4):

You can't store TEXT-columns (which really are blobs) in memory tables. See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html)

Depending on your ultimate goal, you may insert a md5-hash of the TEXT-column instead to preserve entity identity. Otherwise you need to put pdt_desc and such into another table and refer to it's primary key - that will save you some storage/memory too.